# Monkey Talk with Android Studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'

Tags: android, testing, android-studio, intellij-idea, monkeytalk

I am following this [tutorial](https://prativas.wordpress.com/2014/08/15/using-monkeytalk-in-androidstudio/) to make **monkeytalk agent** build so that i can record the event and write some test cases. I have also downloaded [git](https://github.com/georgepapas/android-gradle-monkey-talk-demo/) project with is running but is not showing in **monkey talk IDE** and no events are recording.

I have also made my own project and follow all the steps from **1 to 9**. I am testing it on real device so I `skipped 10th step`. The issue I am facing is that when I sync the project the gradle is building properly but when I am running the project it give me following error.

> > Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> >     No such property: bootClasspath for class: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin

If anyone have any idea, your help is appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After try lots of things i at last successfully integrated MonkeyTalk agent in my APK using Android Studio, here are some details steps that would help a lot.

**Tip** :

- used gradle build version 1.0.0, although 1.2.3 is available but there are some issues with that version of gradle and the monkeytalk client agent apk.
- if you are using google play services use 7.0.0 version

**Steps** :
For steps you can refer to [this](https://prativas.wordpress.com/2014/08/15/using-monkeytalk-in-androidstudio/) document

but here are few problems that I face when following this post, here are the following :

- make libs folder in your app folder and put monkeytalk-agent-2.0.10.jar there, in your app build.gradle use this

  ```
  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  ....
  }
  ```

no need of using

> > monkeytalkCompile fileTree(dir: 'monkey-libs', include: ['*.jar'])

this give me error when i am running the project

no need of writing

> > monkeytalk.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
> >             monkeytalk {
> >                 applicationIdSuffix ".monkey"
> >     }

just use this :

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

i think this will help, if anyone is facing problem please let me know. My build is successfully running on monkeytalk IDE

Comment: I am using the same article to integrate AS with MonkeyTalk. My build grade version is 2.4 and Android Plugin Version is 1.2.3. I get an error saying "Task 'installMonkeytalk' not found in the root project". Do you think if i using Android Plugin Version 1.0.0, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of AspectJ plugin - com.uphyca.gradle:gradle-android-aspectj-plugin:0.9.5' try to use https://github.com/Archinamon/GradleAspectJ-Android.

First add a maven repo link into your repositories block of module build file:

```
maven { url 'https://github.com/Archinamon/GradleAspectJ-Android/raw/master' }
```

Add the plugin to your buildscript's dependencies section:

```
classpath 'com.archinamon:AspectJ-gradle:1.0.15'
```

Apply the aspectj plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.archinamon.aspectj'
```

Now build your project and run.

Note: above changes are there only for step#3 and step#5. other steps will be same.

Comment: thanks man but i just got my answer myself, i appreciate your help again thanks a lot.

Comment: You can try this solution as well .. it works with gradle version 1.2.3. I was also got stuck on this error 2 days ago and i resolved like this without downgrading my gradle plugin.

Comment: it is not working giving me this error Error:Could not find org.fxclub.aspectj:AspectJ-gradle:1.0.15.

Comment: classpath and plugin name got changed.. I updated the steps above.. please try now.