# Android Studio - MonkeyTalk Integration - Issues

Tags: android, testing, android-studio, automated-tests, monkeytalk

I have problems formatting the post. Can someone please edit the post accordingly. Your help is much appreciated.

Also found a similar problem question - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31676760/android-gradle-monkeytalk-build-issue)

I am trying to integrate MonkeyTalk and Android Studio. I am following [this](https://prativas.wordpress.com/2014/08/15/using-monkeytalk-in-androidstudio/) link. When i try to sync build.gradle file in app folder, i get the following error:

```
Error:(37, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'monkeytalkCompile()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'MonkeyTalkTest' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Here is what i have done till now:(as steps from the link above)

Steps:

1. I already have a working android studio project(example) and download MonkeyTalkIDEProfessional from the website.
2. Created folder 'monkey-libs' inside 'app' folder and added 'monkeytalk-agent-2.0.10.jar' file to that directory.
3. Added the following to build.gradle file inside the 'app' folder.

   buildscript {
      repositories {
        mavenCentral()
      }
      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.uphyca.gradle:gradle-android-aspectj-plugin:0.9.5'
      }
    }
4. Added the following line to build.gradle inside 'app' folder: `apply plugin: 'android-aspectj'`
5. Again added the following code to build.gradle inside 'app' folder:

   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    monkeytalkCompile fileTree(dir: 'monkey-libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }
6. Created a folder 'monkeytalk' in 'src' folder and added AndroidManifest.xml file to it with following code:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   ```
7. At this point i am trying to sync build.gradle file and i get the error mentioned earlier.

How can i get past this error?

**EDIT:**

build.gradle file: in app folder

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-aspectj'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.uphyca.gradle:gradle-android-aspectj-plugin:0.9.5'
    }
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "examplepackage.com.monkeytalktest"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    monkeytalkCompile fileTree(dir: 'monkey-libs')
}
```

EDIT 2:

Top-level build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Project structure:

[image]

EDIT 3:

I changed the build.gradle file in 'app' folder as below, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821039/android-studio-and-monkeytalk?rq=1) link. The sync works fine now. When i try to do ./gradlew clean installMonkeyTalk, i get the error in the image below.

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-aspectj'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.uphyca.gradle:gradle-android-aspectj-plugin:0.9.5'
    }
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "examplepackage.com.monkeytalktest"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        monkeytalk.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        monkeytalk {
            applicationIdSuffix ".monkey"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    //monkeytalkCompile fileTree(dir: 'monkey-libs')
    monkeytalkCompile(files("monkey-libs/monkeytalk-agent-2.0.10.jar"))
}
```

Now, i get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue and used different AspectJ plugin instead of uphyca. 
different AspectJ plugin found at: https://github.com/leolin310148/GradleAndroidAspectJPlugin

Its Uses in build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'me.leolin:android-aspectj-plugin:1.0.7'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.leolin.gradle-android-aspectj'
```

Update your build.gradle file to try this solution and let me know if it works. As it worked for me.

All the best !!